# adding JWTDecode to existing iOS project, framework not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have an existing iOS project, and now the times has come to authenticate the users in the apps share extension. For this I need to decode a JWT to see if it is expired or not. I'm used to use jwt with javascript and jwt-decode from npm. For iOS i believe the equivalent to npm is `cocoapods`?

I have found this module: https://github.com/auth0/JWTDecode.swift that claims do do exactly what I need. It even comes with an install guide which explains how to install with cocoapods.

I have follwed these steps to install cocoapods:

Afther that I tried to install the package:

- `cd my-ios-prject`
- `pod init` - this created a Podfile
- in the podfile I added `pod 'JWTDecode', '~> 2.3'`
- `pod install` this downloaded: Using JWTDecode (2.3.0)

I went to Xcode and tried to build the project but im getting the `error:ld: framework not found JWTDecode` which I find confusing, because I didn't even import the lib anywhere yet, I only installed it exactly how the guide said so.

This is what my podfile looks like:

```
target 'appname' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for appname

  target 'appnameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'appname-share' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'JWTDecode', '~> 2.3'
  # Pods for appname-share

end

target 'appname-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for appname-tvOS

  target 'appname-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I only want to use the JWTDecode lib inside the share extension which is why I added it under `target 'appname-share' do`

Please cut me some slack and spare me from "this is duplicate" shaming, I read all the tops posts and they do not solve my issue. Deleting .framework files doesn't do anything. I have also checked and confirmed that in my `project -> target -> build phase -> link binaries` that pods_appname.framework is listed.

Comment: Do you try it on clean project? I created share extension, and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just did that, (`product -> clean build folder`) but still no cigar.

Comment: Not put it that way. Do you try to create absolutely new project?

Comment: Also you can try remove `Podfile.lock`, pods project and try pod install again.

Comment: Thanks. But I have decided to move on, and use Carthage instead of cocaPods. it seems that the generated podfile (from `pod init`) is invalid, and I have too little knowledge to construct one manually.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the pod you have to close the ProjectName.xcodeproj and open and use ProjectName.xcworkspace. In that you can see all your pods too. Got to build phases add the libraryName.a to your linked frameworks and libraries and then, clean and build. It wouldn't throw any error.